# Include output from Write-Output in an email?

Tags: powershell, email

`Write-Output $details` gives the output as a table, I want that output in my email, but when I add it to body part it throws me an error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again

```
$date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y"
$time = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time
$ThresholdFileCount = 1 
$smtp = "address" 
$to = "ok@mail.com"
$from = "abc@def.com"
$subject = "Number of files is above threshold - $date"
$style = "<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color:black; border- 
collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid;border-color: 
black; background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: 
black;} 
</style>"
function filecount {
    param ([string]$path)
    $body += "<body style='font-family: Cambria; font-size: 16pt;'><b><u><a 
name='Monitor'>Monitor</a></u></b></body><br>"
    if (-not (Test-Path $path)) {Throw "Path: $path not found"}
    $count = 0
    $count = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Measure- 
    Object | select -ExpandProperty count
    if ($count -gt $ThresholdFileCount) {
        $details = Get-Item -Path $path| Select-Object PSDrive, @{N = "Parent"; E = 
            {($_.PSParentPath -split "FileSystem::")[1]}
        }, Name, @{N = "FileCount"; E = 
            {$count}
        }
        $body += $details |ConvertTo-Html
        Write-Output $details
    } 
}
Send-MailMessage -FROM $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body BodyAsHtml -Priority High -SmtpServer $smtp
filecount "address"
```

Comment: your function defines `$Body` but never _sends it out_. it only sends out `$Details` ... and never assigns that to anything. so `$Body` does not exist when you call `Send-MailMessage`. [*grin*] ///// if you want to use $Body outside of the function, you must [1] send out the value [2] capture it into a $Var. ///// plus, you NEVER CALL the function. [*frown*]

Comment: M sorry..actually i did call,just forgot to mention here, Now edited..and m new in it and don't know much about how to add body and send it out..

Comment: Your script also defines a variable `$style` but never uses it. Besides that, it is badly formatted

Comment: @omkashyap - now you are calling the function AFTER you use the `$Body` variable. [*grin*] plus, you STILL are not getting the `$Body` variable out of the function. ///// from what i can tell, there is no reason for that to be a function. why don't you simply put the code in place without the function wrapper?

Comment: yes i never used because at first i don't how to use body parts that's why..i just wrote to use it once i do know about that...

Comment: Ohh...How could i do it!!!..i was declaring locally and calling out of the function!!..:(...got it...Thanks anyway...:)